# Documentum 6.5 with JBOSS 5.1 issue

Tags: java, documentum6.5

I'm trying to deploy my War application in JBOSS 5.1 standalone which has been configured for Documentum 6.5.0.038 but when i'm executing the below  code

IDfClient client = DfClient.getLocalClient();

i'm getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.documentum.fc.client.DfClient. even though it is there is App/WEB-INF/lib.Also i tried with jboss-classloading.xml,jboss-deployment-structure.xml which did not help.Added in classpath also which did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running AS with these parameters:

```
-Djboss.vfs.forceCaseSensitive=true -Djboss.vfs.forceVfsJar=true
```